# When using an Erlang supervisor, can I execute code in response to a child exiting?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

When the child exits (either normally or on an error) I want to take some actions. Do I use erlang:monitor/2? And if so how do I get the pid? Also, will I be able to see why it stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, monitor will do the job.

You will get back: `{'DOWN', MonitorRef, Type, Object, Info}`

Where the Object is the pid and Info is the exit reason

You can also do with link and trap_exit, but links are bi-directional so you'd take that child out with you if the parent died.

The easiest way to get the PID of the child process will be to have the child register itself with the listener (the one using monitor) when it starts. Have it send self() and then the listener can monitor that PID.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the pid to pass to monitor?

Comment: If it's your child process, you must have spanwed it, no?  Just keep track of it

Comment: Ok, pardon my confusion, but I don't think I started the child myself. I returned a child spec out of init() and the supervisor library started it, didn't it?

Comment: You are talking about children of some supervisor that started a process?  When you said child, i thought you meant you had a gen_server that spawned children.  Easiest way to do something like this will be to have the gen_server that you want to take action, act as a registry.  child starts up and does gen_server:cast(registry_guy,{register_me,self()}).  the process that will take action should register as "registry_guy", then in handle_cast, you get {register_me,Pid} and monitor that Pid... then you will see them die... make sense?

Comment: A Ha! This is what I needed. Thanks. I edited the answer to include this.